# ORA-03134: Connections to this server version are no longer supported

Tags: asp.net, .net, oracle, iis

Environment:Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1586.0

Backend: Oracle 9i

Tools : Visual Studio 2012, ODAC 11.2 Version

The application works fine when I debug through Visual studio 2012 and all CRUD operation works perfectly.

**But when I deploy it to the IIS server it said "ORA-03134: Connections to this server version are no longer supported as in below image"**

[image]

**IIS configuration(Application Pool) is as follows :**

[image]

Comment: The terminal patchset for 9iR2 is _over 10 years old_. Time to upgrade already.

Comment: The client is not willing to upgrade the backend side.

Comment: Then you need to use tools that support that ancient version.

Comment: So I am using ODAC 11.2 Version that supports 9i but the problem is, it does not work in IIS but works perfectly in Visual study debuging mode

Comment: Here is [an Oracle forum thread which has a similar sounding problem](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2603090?start=0&tstart=0). The solution there was to change the configuration of the GAC. Maybe it could help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a gateway DB version 11.2 to access the old database 9.2.0.8.
Create a dblink from the gateway DB version 11.2 for the old database 9.2.0.8.

```
C:\oracle\instantclient_12_2>.\sqlplus.exe  scott/tiger@oracle11

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Mon Feb 18 07:31:38 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> select * from dept@oracle9;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        12 RESEARCH       SARATOGA
        10 ACCOUNTING     CLEVELAND
        11 ART            SALEM
        13 FINANCE        BOSTON
        21 SALES          PHILA.
        22 SALES          ROCHESTER
        42 INT'L          SAN FRAN

7 rows selected.
```

Oracle client 11.2.0.4 can connect to Oracle RDBMS 9.2.0.8.

```
C:\oracle\instantclient_11_2>.\sqlplus.exe  scott/tiger@oracle9

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Mon Feb 18 07:37:22 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.8.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP and Oracle Data Mining options
JServer Release 9.2.0.8.0 - Production

SQL>
```

Oracle client 12.2.0.1 can not connect to Oracle RDBMS 9.2.0.8.

```
C:\oracle\instantclient_12_2>.\sqlplus.exe  scott/tiger@oracle9

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Mon Feb 18 07:36:45 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-03134: Connections to this server version are no longer supported.
```